# Cancellation of CompletableFuture controlled by ExecutorService

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have an `ExecutorService` which forwards the computed data to a `CompletableFuture`:

```
class DataRetriever {
    private final ExecutorService service = ...;

    public CompletableFuture<Data> retrieve() {
        final CompletableFuture<Data> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

        service.execute(() -> {
            final Data data = ... fetch data ...
            future.complete(data);
        });
        return future;
    }
}
```

I want the client/user to be able to cancel the task:

```
final DataRetriever retriever = new DataRetriever();
final CompletableFuture<Data> future = retriever().retrieve();

future.cancel(true);
```

This does not work, as this cancels the outer `CompletableFuture`, but not the inner future as scheduled in the executor service.

Is it somehow possible to propagate `cancel()` on the outer future to the inner future?

Comment: Why are you using `CompletableFuture` in the first place? Why not just execute a `Callable<Data>` and return the resulting `Future` from `retrieve()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CompletableFuture#cancel` really only serves the purpose of marking a `CompletableFuture` as cancelled. It does nothing to notify an executing task to stop, because it has no relationship to any such task.

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#cancel-boolean-) hints at this

> `mayInterruptIfRunning`  - this value has no effect in this implementation because interrupts are not used to control processing.

The *inner* future in your example is a `Future`, not a `CompletableFuture`, and it does have a relation to the executing `Runnable` (or `Callable`). Internally, since it know what `Thread` the task is executing on, it can send it an `interrupt` to attempt to stop it.

One option is to return a tuple of some sorts (eg. some POJO) that provides a reference to both your `CompletableFuture` and to the `Future` returned by `ExecutorService#submit`. You can use the `Future` to `cancel` if you need to. You'd have to remember to `cancel` or `complete` your `CompletableFuture` so that other parts of your code don't remain blocked/starved forever.

Comment: The problem with returning a tuple/pojo (containing the outer and the inner future) is that the client becomes aware of the internal implementation. He shouldn't care from his perspective. It would be useful if we can chain the outer and the inner future somehow.

Comment: Canceling the `Future` returned by `ExecutorService#submit` seems worth a try.

Comment: @DaveTeezo There are more complex solutions, like extending `CompletableFuture` to wrap a related `Future`, but I find the implementation rather unmaintainable and unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, which Pillar touched on, is to extend `CompletableFuture`. Here's one method that's quite similar to your existing code. It also handles exceptions, which is a nice bonus.

```
class CancelableFuture<T> extends CompletableFuture<T> {
    private Future<?> inner;

    /**
     * Creates a new CancelableFuture which will be completed by calling the
     * given {@link Callable} via the provided {@link ExecutorService}.
     */
    public CancelableFuture(Callable<T> task, ExecutorService executor) {
        this.inner = executor.submit(() -> complete(task));
    }

    /**
     * Completes this future by executing a {@link Callable}. If the call throws
     * an exception, the future will complete with that exception. Otherwise,
     * the future will complete with the value returned from the callable.
     */
    private void complete(Callable<T> callable) {
        try {
            T result = callable.call();
            complete(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            completeExceptionally(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterrupt) {
        return inner.cancel(mayInterrupt) && super.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Then, in `DataRetriever`, you can simply do:

```
public CompletableFuture<Data> retrieve() {
    return new CancelableFuture<>(() -> {... fetch data ...}, service);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With my [Tascalate Concurrent](https://github.com/vsilaev/tascalate-concurrent) library your code may be rewritten as following:

```
class DataRetriever {
  private final ExecutorService service = ...;

  public Promise<Data> retrieve() {
    return CompletableTask.supplyAsync(() -> {
      final Data data = ... fetch data ...
      return data;
    }, service);
  }
}
```

`Promise` and `CompletableTask` are classes from my library, you can read more in [my blog](https://vsilaev.com/2017/07/29/announcing-tascalate-concurrent/)

Answer (score 0):

By adding an exception handler to the outer future, you can have the call to `cancel` be passed down to the inner future. This works because `CompletableFuture.cancel` causes the future to complete exceptionally with a `CancellationException`.

```
private final ExecutorService service = ...;

public CompletableFuture<Data> retrieve() {
    final CompletableFuture<Data> outer = new CompletableFuture<>();

    final Future<?> inner = service.submit(() -> {
        ...
        future.complete(data);
    });

    outer.exceptionally((error) -> {
        if (error instanceof CancellationException) {
            inner.cancel(true);
        }
        return null; // must return something, because 'exceptionally' expects a Function
    });

    return outer;
}
```

The call to `outer.exceptionally` creates a new `CompletableFuture`, so it doesn't affect the cancellation or exception status of `outer` itself. You can still append any other `CompletionStage` you like to `outer`, including another `exceptionally` stage, and it will operate as expected.